# How to put image programmatically to match all layout?

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I want to match an image on all layout.

I got an image here:
[image]

I tried everything, here is the code

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mid_linear_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            ...>
            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tiles_tables"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/row1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="3">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/tile1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        />
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/tile2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        />
```

here I got the main function:

```
    ImageView[] tiles = new ImageView[9];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) 
    {
    tiles[i].setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("tile_image1","drawable", getPackageName()));
    // this is just to get one image for all imageViews
    // here stars the problem
    tiles[i].getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    tiles[i].getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    }
```

I want image to match all tile layout.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you want to 3 images in single row with same height and width (not static but as per resolution)?

Comment: hi, thx. 3 images per row. 9 x 9 tiles. same width and height. well resolution.. i mean there are different screens.. so they must stretch. i dont know why i got the white border between them...

Answer (score 1):

You Can use list with `recyclerView` and set `grid adapter` with `3 colums`. 
for make square of particular `item` you need to use `ContraintLayout` as `parent` then in `chlid` apply ratio `1:1` for `image`.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    tools:src="@drawable/ic_chat_bubble_black_24dp"
    />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Or you can refer this also

```
  @Override
  public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) 
  {
    View view = LayoutInflater
        .from(parent.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.item_list, null);

   int height = parent.getMeasuredHeight() / 4;
   int width = parent.getMeasuredWidth();

  view.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(width, height));

 return new ViewHolder(view);
}
```

Comment: so the problem is in xml ? you say?

Comment: i need 9 x 9 tiles. also they should stretch for different phone screens

Comment: actually problem is in the way which you had used, You need to use recyclerview with GridLayoutManager and there is some fixes also in xml file like

you have to use contraintlayout as parent then your image will be in that layout. 
After that in Design tab (one is text tab and another is design tab in studio) select imagview then right side you got constraint and then you need to click top-left corner in that constraint print so it will be give equal sizes of images in particular row. In short by this you can get your solution

Comment: this above solution will work in all screens resolutions